# Can we use multiple buttons for select files from internal storage and upload on database using same button

Tags: android, database, firebase-realtime-database

In my activity how can I use  two select buttons in same activity to select files from internal storage and upload on database using same upload button

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just you need do on onActivityResult put upload button method  when is selected file. It's gonna upload straight file when it's selected.

Comment: can you elebrate with the some line of code that how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

Look at this

```
 public void choosefile() {

        StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

        Intent cInt = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        cInt.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(output));
        startActivityForResult(cInt,100);

}
```

and on result

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
     upload(media_path);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cancelled front", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```